# ReactJS: DOM property not recognized

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I am creating a ReactJS component with a search field described like this:

**SearchNotes.js**

```
<label for='search_notes'>Search</label>
<input id='search_notes' type='text' onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPressed}></input>
```

Everything is working fine, but I am getting this error here:

[image]

This property `for` clearly exists in `label` tags. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is occurring because `for` is not an attribute on React elements. Use `htmlFor` instead, as the error suggests. React doesn't use any JavaScript keywords as attribute names like `class` (which is `className`) or `for` (which is `htmlFor`).

Comment: Shame on me! I didn't notice that `for`, being a reserved word for Javascript, would have a replacement in React, just like `class`! Thanks for helping me!